# remove item from "running total" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, math

This is my code for a shopping cart (the total so far, but a shopping cart eventually) i'm trying to put the code in to minus the clicked item's value from the "total", this is my code:

```
$('.addtocart').click(function(){
                $('#cart').show();
                var omPartNo = $(this).next().text();
                var supPartNo = $(this).next().next().text();
                var cat = $(this).next().next().next().text();
                var desc = $(this).next().next().next().next().text();
                var manuf = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().text();
                var list = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().next().text();
                var disc = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().next().next().text();
                var priceEach = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().text();
                $('#cart table').append('<tr class="tableRow"><td><a class="removeItem" href="#"><img src="/admin/images/delete.png"></img></a><td>' + omPartNo + '</td><td>' + supPartNo + '</td><td>' + cat + '</td><td>' + desc + '</td><td>' + manuf + '</td><td>' + list + '</td><td>' + disc + '</td><td class="price">' + priceEach + '</td></tr>');
                    var total = 0;
                    $('.price').each(function() { 
                        total += parseFloat($.text([this]));
                    });
                    $('#subtotal span').html(total.toFixed(2));

            });

            $('.removeItem').live('click',function(){                                       
                $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
            });
```

So when i click the .removeItem i need it to subtract from the "subtotal span" if possible??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function to calculate the total, and call it whenever there is reason to re-calculate..

```
 function calcTotal(){
     var total = 0;
     $('.price').each(function() { 
         total += parseFloat($(this).text());
       });
     $('#subtotal span').html(total.toFixed(2));
  }
```

and now change

```
$('#cart table').append('<tr class="tableRow"><td><a class="removeItem" href="#"><img src="/admin/images/delete.png"></img></a><td>' + omPartNo + '</td><td>' + supPartNo + '</td><td>' + cat + '</td><td>' + desc + '</td><td>' + manuf + '</td><td>' + list + '</td><td>' + disc + '</td><td class="price">' + priceEach + '</td></tr>');
                    var total = 0;
                    $('.price').each(function() { 
                        total += parseFloat($.text([this]));
                    });
                    $('#subtotal span').html(total.toFixed(2));

            });

            $('.removeItem').live('click',function(){                                       
                $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
            });
```

to

```
$('#cart table').append('<tr class="tableRow"><td><a class="removeItem" href="#"><img src="/admin/images/delete.png"></img></a><td>' + omPartNo + '</td><td>' + supPartNo + '</td><td>' + cat + '</td><td>' + desc + '</td><td>' + manuf + '</td><td>' + list + '</td><td>' + disc + '</td><td class="price">' + priceEach + '</td></tr>');
                    calcTotal();

            });

            $('.removeItem').live('click',function(){                                       
                $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
                calcTotal();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr');
var price = parseFloat(tableRow.find('.price').text());
total -= price.toFixed(2);

tableRow.remove();
```